# Memory leak in php

Tags: php, memory-leaks, addslashes

I am having a problem understanding why this part of my code is causing a memory leak:

```
for($i=0; $i<count($values); $i++){
        $values[$i] = addslashes($values[$i]);
}
```

To put the code in context, i have a previously built array called values, which has all the values to be inserted into a database. all the fields are strings so i need to escape all of them and for this application addslashes or mysql_real_escape_string are a good choice imo.

Now the strange thing is that as soon as i added the part shown above, i get a message like this:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 24 bytes)
```

I understood that this generated a memory leak but i don't know why.

Digging in, i commented out the only line in the for loop, leaving the for statement just for curiosity, and the leak is gone. Any ideas what could this possibly mean?

PS: The strings are all UTF8 encoded, could that be a problem?

EDIT:

The array contains something like this :

```
Array ( 
    [dossier] => 002A 
    [permis] => 
    [adresse] => 18, rue Bellevue
    [ville] => Ste-Anne-des-Lacs (Québec)
    [province] =>
    [code_postal] => J0R 1B0
    [numero_centrale] => N/A
    [routes] => De la Gare, droite chemin Avila jusqu'au bout et droite chemin Ste-Anne-des-lacs sur 1,8 km et droite sur Bellevue.
)
```

Comment: How big is the array? And each item of the array?

Comment: What are you using `addslashes` for? I get the feeling you are doing it wrong.

Comment: Though it won't fix your memory issues, you should not put `count` in the loop like that; always assign a the count to some variable prior to the loop and use that variable in the loop instead. The way you have it written, `count()` will be called for each iteration through `$values`

Comment: @Wug, mysql_real_escape_string causes the same problem, i was using it first but i switched to addslashes to check if this works instead

Comment: @PeeHaa: I completely agree with you on using PDO but i don't have control over this, it's a shared code

Comment: @DanyKhalife either way you should never ever use addslashes for sqli prevention

Comment: If you had used a foreach loop this wouldn't have happened haha

Comment: @AdamSack i don't know what i was thinking lol

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your array has string keys, but you are checking/assigning numeric keys. As @nickb notes, each time you add a numeric key, `count($values)` increases by one, so you have an infinite loop. Hence the memory exhaustion.

Check with a debugger, or better yet, switch to a `foreach` loop or one of the `array_*` functions (`array_walk()`, `array_map()`, etc. depending on what you are trying to do).

@Jeremy correctly points out that you should not be using `addslashes()` to escape your strings.  Look at `mysqli_real_escape_string()` (as he suggests), or better yet, consider using `PDO` if you can.

Comment: for db insertions you should be using mysqli_real_escape_string

Comment: @Jeremy That's true (sort of--you should really be using PDO and not inserting strings at all if you can), but not what the poster is asking about.

Comment: "which has all the values to be inserted into a database" How so?

Comment: A more precise explanation of what is happening would be: Because `count()` is being called on each iteration **and** new elements are always being added (`count()` starts off at 8 and increase by 1 on each iteration, while `$i` started at 0), the loop is an infinite loop.

Comment: yes i agree with Trott, i prefer PDO it does all that already but in this case i am stuck with others' decision

Comment: Added @Jeremy's comments and my own to the answer. (Hope he'll consider undoing the downvote, but whatever, either way. :-) )

Comment: Added @nickb's better explanation than the one I originally had of the source of the infinite loop.

Comment: Thanks @nickb even though i understood what was happening when Trott pointed out my problem its better to expose it clearly for others with the same problem

Answer (score 2):

Try using [array_walk](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk.php) instead.

Also, do not count on every loop. Get the count before you put it in the loop conditional. Since this is for the database, you should really be using: [mysqli_real_escape_string](http://nz.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php)

Comment: Using mysqli_real_escape_string will not help the memory issue mentioned in the question.

Comment: It's the proper way to escape the data. The issue is it's done wrong in the first place

Comment: That's fine if you wish to mention that in passing.  But your answer does not answer the question.  The issue is the string keys, not integer keys.  Mentioning array_walk and real_escape_string do not answer the question.

Comment: Agreed, but the logic is wrong to begin with. Guiding someone to do the wrong solution does not make it correct. Teaching them the proper method just makes more sense

Comment: Then the data you provided is not an answer, but a comment.  Yes?  I invite you to click the link on the top of the page that says "meta".  In there we can discuss semantics and how to provide data to help people grow, while still answering their intended question.